# Why is __SCROLLPOSITIONY is not recognized in IE? It throws a JS runtime error of undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, internet-explorer, cross-browser

I have some code to help keep some popup divs in view after a postback because in our asp.net page we have `MaintainScrollPositionOnPostback` set to true. What I am doing is getting the amount of vertical scroll and offsetting the placement of the div by this value so that after the postback when the vertical scroll is maintained, the new popup div will be centered in view. This works fine in Chrome (of course), but when testing it out in IE 11, I am greeted with this javascript runtime error: `0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: '__SCROLLPOSITIONY' is undefined`.

Here's the line of JS code where the issue is occuring, it's pretty simple:

```
var topValue = parseInt(__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value);
```

How can I get this value to be found in IE 11? I realize there are (possibly) better solutions for this including using alerts, but for time constraints and consistency, among other reasons, let's not go down this route. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use MaintainScrollPositionOnPostBack, ASP generates hidden fields for scroll positions and injects some scripts as well, for Microsoft browsers, you must handle this differently by using a check in your JavaScript, called __nonMSDOMBrowser, here's an example I found online of using it.

```
function WebForm_RestoreScrollPosition() {
    if (__nonMSDOMBrowser) {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONX'].value, theForm.elements['__SCROLLPOSITIONY'].value);
    }
    else {
        window.scrollTo(theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONX.value, theForm.__SCROLLPOSITIONY.value);
    }
    if ((typeof(theForm.oldOnLoad) != "undefined") && (theForm.oldOnLoad != null)) {
        return theForm.oldOnLoad();
    }
    return true;
}

theForm.oldOnLoad = theForm.onLoad;
theForm.onLoad = WebForm_RestoreScrollPosition;
```

I know this isn't *exactly* what you're after, but it should be enough to point you in the right direction and give you some things to try.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much, this is exactly what I needed.